# Loss of data while copying from CSV to SQL

Tags: python, python-3.x, vertica

I'm using Vertica Python to copy data from a csv file to a table on Vertica. While it works pretty fast, I'm losing about 700 rows of data. I've tried to delete the csv file and load from a new csv file, yet I'm facing the same issue.  Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong in my code?

```
with open('new.csv', 'r',encoding="utf8") as file:
    csv_file = file.read()
    copy_cmd = "COPY Account FROM STDIN DELIMITER ','"
    cur.copy(copy_cmd, csv_file)
    connection.commit()
```

Is it something in the code that's making me lose hundreds of rows from the csv file?

Comment: Which rows? Have you checked the syntax on those row's so there's no malformed data etc? What does a good row look like? Is it random rows, the last rows or some of the first row's that get chopped out?

Comment: Consider using the `REJECTED DATA` option to capture invalid rows, if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use REJECTED DATA and EXCEPTIONS to find out what rows are missing and why. You need to specify a path for each. Rejected data will show which rows were not copied, and exceptions shows what the error was.

```
COPY Account FROM STDIN DELIMITER ',' REJECTED DATA '/path/to/rejections.txt' EXCEPTIONS '/path/to/exceptions.txt';
```